# How to group by records from database based on date (day) c#?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq

I know this could be a possible duplicate question, pardon me if it is.

Is there a way to `GroupBy` all the records from the database by date?

So:

- say i have multiple records for this date 22/05/2022
- and say i have multiple records from this date: 23/05/2022

Can i group all the records based on date parameter 22/05 and 23/05?

So that i would end up with a list containing `n` list for each day.

**Here is what i did:**

```cs
var grpQuery = await ctx.Registration.GroupBy(c => c.DateReference.Day).ToListAsync();
```

Where:

- `Registration` is my table from where i am pulling the data
- `DateReference` is a `Date` object containing the date

But i am getting this error "the linq expession could not be translated".

Can somone give me some advice on this?

### EDIT

I tried this but it seems not to load any data, even setting break a break point will not return anything:

```cs
                var grpQuery = await query.GroupBy(d => new { DateReference = d.DateReference.Date }).Select(c => new RegistrationViewModel()
 {
   RegistrationId = c.FirstOrDefault().RegistrationId,
   PeopleId = c.FirstOrDefault().PeopleId,
   DateReference = c.Key.DateReference,
   DateChange = c.FirstOrDefault().DateChange,
   UserRef = c.FirstOrDefault().UserRef,
   CommissionId = c.FirstOrDefault().CommissionId,
   ActivityId = c.FirstOrDefault().ActivityId,
   MinuteWorked = c.FirstOrDefault().MinuteWorked,
 }).OrderBy(d => d.DateReference).ToListAsync();
```

Where:

- `RegistrationViewModel` contains all those properties including `DateReference`
- If i call the method using the API is stuck at "pending"

Comment: First, don't. The equivalent query in the database would be `GROUP BY DATEPART(day,registration.Date)` which can't use indexes and therefore is *slow*. In such cases a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) prepopulated with eg 10-20 years worth of dates with explicit, indexed columns for Year, Month, Day, Week number, Quarter, Semester, names etc is used. This makes date-related queries a lot easier. You only have to join with the Calendar table on date, group by the periods you want and display the totals

Comment: EF couldn't handle the query because you didn't provide a select function. You grouped the values and then what? You need some sort of aggregation function in your selection to retrieve the related data

Comment: Okay but still even selecting doesn't work, it is as if the query is pending forever. I'll update my question with the latest edits.

Comment: Which EF or EF Core version are you using?

Comment: I am using EF Core 6 with dot net 6

Comment: Why are you using `FirstOrDefault` in a `GROUP BY` query? What are you trying to retrieve? GROUP BY is used to sum or count, not retrieve individual rows. A GROUP, by definition, *reduces* rows. `FirstOrDefault` isn't an aggregate function. There's no equivalent aggregate function in SQL either. There's no `first row in the group`. The closest `FIRST_VALUE(field) OVER(..)` returns the first or last value in the existing result set based on an explicit order

Comment: I was trying to GroupBy date and then select all the records grouped and put them in a list. I don't know if that is correct.

Comment: That doesn't explain what you want. GROUP eliminates individual rows. Are you trying to load the individual rows and nest them by day? You can't use `GroupBy` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't. Even if the query was fixed, the equivalent query in the database would be GROUP BY DATEPART(day,registration.Date) which can't use indexes and therefore is slow.

According [to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions) the equivalent of `DATEPART(day, @dateTime)` is `dateTime.Day`. The query still needs to have a proper `Select` though.

A correct query would be :

```
counts = ctx.Registrations.GroupBy(r=>r.RegistrationDate.Day)
                 .Select(g=>new {Day=g.Key,Count=g.Count())
                 .ToList();
```

The equivalent, slow query would be

```
SELECT DATEPART(day,registration.Date) as Day,count(*)
FROM Registrations
GROUP BY DATEPART(day,registration.Date)
```

Things get worse if we have to eg filter by date. The query would have to scan the entire table because it wouldn't be able to use any indexes covering the `Date` column

```
SELECT DATEPART(day,registration.Date) as Day,count(*)
FROM Registrations
WHERE Date >'20220901'
GROUP BY DATEPART(day,registration.Date)
```

Imagine having to scan 10 years of registrations only to get the current month.

This is a reporting query. For date related reports, using a prepopulated [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) can make the query *infinitely* easier.

```
SELECT Calendar.Day,COUNT(*)
FROM Registrations r
INNER JOIN Calendar on r.RegistrationDate=Calendar.Date
GROUP BY Calendar.Day
```

or

```
SELECT Calendar.Year, Calendar.Semester, Calendar.Day,COUNT(*)
FROM Registrations r
INNER JOIN Calendar on r.RegistrationDate=Calendar.Date
WHERE Calendar.Year = @someYear
GROUP BY Calendar.Year, Calendar.Semester,Calendar.Day
```

A [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) or Date dimension is a table with prepopulated dates, years, months, semesters or any other reporting period along with their names or anything needed to make reporting easier. Such a table can contain eg 10 or 20 years of data without taking a lot of space. To speed up queries, the columns can be aggressively indexed without taking too much extra space.

Doing the same in EF Core requires mapping `Calendar` as an entity and performing the JOIN in LINQ. This is one of the cases where it makes no sense to add a relation between entities :

```
var query=from registration in ctx.Registrations
          join date in Calendar 
              on registration.Date equals Calendar.Date
          group registration by date.Day into g
          select new { Day=g.Key, Count=g.Count()};
var counts = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I tried the var query ... but inner join does not exists. I am still a newby to this so sorry if i don't get obvious things. Also where do i get that Calendar?

Comment: Oops. [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins) should be alone. I included a link to an article that explains Calendar tables and how to create them in the anser

Answer (score -1):

If you are using EF Core Please try this:

```
var grpQuery = await ctx.Registration.Select(a=>new {Re = a, G = (EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(a.End,DateTime.Today))}).ToListAsync().ContinueWith(d=>d.Result.GroupBy(a=>a.G));
```

Comment: It gives me this error: "The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Registration>()\r\n    .GroupBy(c => __Functions_0\r\n        .DateDiffDay(\r\n            startDate: c.DateReference, \r\n            endDate: 01/01/0001 00:00:00))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."

Comment: Updated the answer, use DateTime.Today instead of MinValue.

Comment: Still throwing the same error, don't know why...

Comment: Please try again.

Comment: The query groups by day, not by the difference from some arbitrary starting point. Using `DATEDIFF` is simply the wrong function

Comment: Yeah i was about to say that, but thanks anyway.

Comment: At the time of running the query, it will group by the difference between TODAY(arbitrary date) and column value. Because, TODAY(arbitrary date) is constant for the entire query it will solve the purpose.

Comment: Still says that DateDiffDay doesn't have overload method

Comment: I get what you mean now, and i think it could work

Comment: I have updated the answer to overcome current limitations on EF functions. Please check now.

Comment: It executes ( a bit slow and doesen't give me what i need), thanks all of you for your suggestion, i am afraid i have to call it a no-go. I've been on this all day and figured nothing (plus the target table has 200K+ records).